# WebLogic Inactive Connection Timeout and JTA timeout

Tags: database, database-connection, weblogic, connection-timeout

1. Should the JTA timeout in WebLogic be same as 'Inactive Connection Timeout'?
2. We have set the 'Inactive Connection Timeout' to X seconds. We have an application deployed on WebLogic, which issues queries which take above X seconds to execute. However the we do not see any exceptions and the queries succeed.

   Can you please explain when does 'Inactive Connection Timeout' can be effective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting documentation:

> The number of seconds of inactivity after which reserved connections
>   will forcibly be released back into the pool. When set to 0 (the
>   default), this feature is disabled.

Usually "Inactive Connection Timeout" is used to prevent connection leaking.

If you what your queries to timeout after certain period:

1. set 'Statement Timeout' on datasource level
2. set it explicitly in your code

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My SQL queries take more than 'Inactive Connection Timeout' to execute - so wondering how come the queries succeed?

Comment: During your query, connection is not in inactive state. That's why it's not being reclaimed to the pool.

Comment: Thanks. So I can keep 'Inactive Connection Timeout' less than 'Statement Timeout' safely?